# How to host the xampp's local database on the webserver

Tags: mysql, xampp, webserver, global, local-database

I have made a database locally using Xampp and now i want that database to be hosted on webserver. i have no idea how to do so i have also searched but i'm unable to get any proper tutorial or detailed guide for this. Really looking forward for some guideline, Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "making the database global". Do you have a public webserver and you want to deploy your application and data to this server? Please try to change your question in a way that makes it clear what you try to do.

Comment: @luksch Re-check now. actually i want my local database to be accessed by others that would be done by hosting it on a web server, right? so i want to know how to do that!?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PhpMyAdmin on the target Webserver, you could create a Database dump of your local Database via PhpMyAdmin (select your Db, then Click "Export") which you can then import into the target Server.

Comment: can you suggest me any Webserver that would be good in my situation? As I'm new to the Web side i don't know much related to this.

Answer (score 0):

1. export your database and save.
2. Upload into webserver.
3. Create database,user and setting user previlages in remote host.
4. import the sql.
5. Done.

if the sql file is large, better process with ssh.

Comment: Thanks!! but can you tell me What WebServer should i use and how to deal with it. Actually i'm new to this Web side and i don't have much idea about it.